# How to form the chain in database with previous records using mongodb with java code

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-mail

I want to store emails using mongodb. But now, I want to form the chain in database because to communicate with the user very easily. That's why I want to pass one parameter to the email while sending.

How will i do that? Please give me any suggestions.

Comment: How are you going to retrieve the documents? Is it going to issue N queries for N docs? What happens if you actually get a tree (e.g. more than one response to a message)?
Have you checked how mail clients (like Thunderbird) are handling and displaying the message trees?
Adding one more field, like the ID of the previous document, shouldn't be a big deal, but it might have some consequences.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "chain".

Comment: chain means what we think is it forms a one flow belonging to that conversation. In this we want to check whether the email is belongs to previous one or new one.

Comment: Do a search for "email conversation threading".

Comment: yes i searched but i didn't get any result. I am not able to get Message-ID(unique purpose)